# How to set different value of same variable?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a function that shows different result of different module.
In `global.h` I set `strModuleName`:

```
std::string strModuleName = "no_name";

std::string GetModuleName() {
    return strModuleName;
}
```

And in `module1.h`, I set module name to "module1":

```
#include "global.h"

strModuleName = "module1";
...
void some_function() {
    GetModuleName();  //I want to get "module1"
}
```

in `module2.h` ,set module name to "module2":

```
#include "global.h"

strModuleName = "module2";
...
void some_function2() {
    GetModuleName();  //I want to get "module2"
}
```

But it's a redefinition error. Is there any way to make it?

Comment: Since you tagged with c++, you can consider to have `strModuleName` a member of a class representing each module (with a method `GetModuleName()`).

Comment: Having global variables is a design smell (and makes unit testing harder), and I would strongly recommend not even trying something like this.
Though you might try something like `static constexpr std::string_view GetModuleName() { return "moduleX";}` and then hope that someone doesn't both include "module1.h" and "module2.h". Or as @wohlstad says inject the module name through a class wrapper.

Comment: Tip: Try `static` in the functions.

Comment: Are those classes inherited from another class? If so, you can create a constructor for each class with a default value .

Comment: I'm assuming by "module" you mean *translation unit*? Because *modules* are something else in C++.

Answer (score 1):

"In global.h I set strModuleName"

To be precise, you **define** and **initialize** `strModuleName` in `global.h`.

And `global.h` is #include'd twice. So you also have two definitions and two initializations. That's not possible.

You also have a double definition of `GetModuleName`.

In header `module1.h`, you have no reasonable control about how often other files will include you. So you can't reasonably define variables there either. Additionally, you can't have assignment statements like `strModuleName = "module1";` outside functions.

What you *can* do:

```
// module1.h
namespace module1 {
  inline auto GetModuleName() {
    return "Module1";
  }
}
```

The `namespace` allows you to define `GetModuleName`, because the full name `module1::GetModuleName` will differ from `module2::GetModuleName`.

The `inline` tells the compiler that there can be multiple definitions of this function (due to `module1.h` being included in multiple translation units)